$\phi * Hf = H\phi * f$ (almost) everywhere.
When teaching about Hilbert transform, it seems that my professor used the following:

Let $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}$, $f \in L^{p}$ for $1<p<\infty$ (or I guess assume $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$ for simplicity), $\phi * Hf = H\phi * f$ (almost) everywhere.

I think when $f \in L^{2}(\Bbb R^{n})$, we can prove this by taking Fourier transform on both side. But otherwise, I'm not sure if this is true. I tried doing a change of variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Actually, maybe it's just as simple as taking limit, since we know hilbert transform can be extended from $L^2$ to $L^p$

Please explain the notation. What is $H$?

@温泽海 The canonical notation of Hilbert transform.

$Hf=(p.v.\frac1x)\ast f$. We know convolutions are associative for nice enough function, for which Schwartz functions are the cases, so $\phi\ast (p.v.\frac1x\ast f)=(p.v.\frac1x\ast\phi)\ast f$ for $f\in S(\Bbb R)$. By the $L^p$ boundedness of Hilbert transform the equality holds via the density argument.
